# SQL Server : build valid tree filtering invalid branches

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree

I have a table with following data:

```
ID     ParentID    Name
-----------------------
 1       NULL      OK1
 2        1        OK2
 3        2        OK3
 5        4        BAD1
 6        5        BAD2
```

So I need to take only those lines, which are linked to `ParentID = NULL` OR valid children of such lines (i.e: OK3 is valid because it's linked to OK2, which is linked to OK1, which is linked to NULL, which is valid.)

But BAD1 and BAD 2 are not valid because those are not linked to a line, which is linked to NULL.

The best solution I figured out is a procedure + function. And function is called as many times as the max number of link levels in the table.

Can anybody suggest better solution for such task?

Comment: I think this will require a recursive query to solve.

Comment: I support Tim's idea of using recursive logic, you could implement a CTE query. Take a look to this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is love, and a basic [**recursive CTE**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) :-)

Create and populate sample data (**Please** save us this step in future questions):

```
DECLARE @T as table
(
    ID int,
    ParentID int,
    Name varchar(4)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, NULL, 'OK1'),
(2, 1, 'OK2'),
(3, 2, 'OK3'),
(5, 4, 'BAD1'),
(6, 5, 'BAD2')
```

The CTE and query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, ParentId, Name
    FROM @T 
    WHERE ParentId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT T1.ID, T1.ParentId, T1.Name
    FROM @T T1
    INNER JOIN CTE T2 ON T1.ParentID = T2.ID
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

Results:

```
ID          ParentId    Name
----------- ----------- ----
1           NULL        OK1
2           1           OK2
3           2           OK3
```

Comment: Plus 1 for this *(Please save us this step in future questions)* ;)

Comment: @Prdp Thanks. It's a recent addition to my answers. I find people tend to fulfill this request better then just asking them in the comments "please edit your question to include the relevant tables ddl..." I write all the time.  I hope this trend will catch on so that we will see more properly formatted questions.